# Partial model editing and validation in Backbone

Tags: backbone.js

I'm after some advice on how to handle partial editing and validation of a model in Backbone.

I have a payslip model with 20+ properties. The user can edit part of the payslip (e.g. the overtime properties), the app will display a modal dialog and the user can change the four properties related to overtime.

The modal dialog for editing overtime has a related Backbone view 'OvertimeEditor' which contains the view logic. There are 10 such views / modal dialogs for handling different properties.

The Editor views don't interact directly with the models, there's a mediator for this. The mediator calls a parameterised function on the view which populates and displays the modal dialog. When the user hits save the view then calls a parameterised function on the mediator which updates the model properties.

How should I handle validation within a dialog? i.e. I just want to validate the four properties in question, not the entire model.

The editor views don't currently use a model. Should I create models just for use with the editor views? e.g. a PayslipOvertime model? Or should I manually implement validation in the view (doesn't sound right)?

Comment: Create per-view models with just enough attributes for their editors, then they can initialize themselves based on the main big model and you can have a method to merge a mini-model back into the main model. You can share validation code through a library of validator functions. The extra layer of mini-models makes it harder to accidentally edit the wrong things and I find that editing a copy and merging it when you're done (i.e. git style fork/commit/merge editing) simplifies things a lot.

Comment: Gotcha. I'm assuming that, in my case, I'd shove the code for transferring properties in the mediator?

Comment: Or possible the mini-model constructor (`mini_model = new MiniModel({ full_model: model })`). Depends where it makes sense in your specific context (as usual :).

Answer (score 0):

I would consider continuing to maintain a single set of payslip models, each of which contains a collection of properties that have an 'editable' member.  This way you can avoid allocating additional objects.

```
[
  {name: "Overtime", value:10, editable:true, required:true },
  {name: "hours", value:40, editable:false, required:false },
  ...
]
```

If I am understanding your question correctly, I would rather rely on these editable or required properties for validation rather than create additional models.